# WPF window title with databinding and constant string

Tags: c#, wpf, events, binding, properties

I have a description´s textbox that I want to add to some constant text in the window title. Like "Description: " + Description.
Can I easily do this in the xaml?

My first approach was to create a new property that returns the Description´s value with the constant string. The problem is that I don´t get PropertyChanged event so the window´s title doesnt refresh. I was thinking of creating an event on the Description´s seter but I think its too ugly.

Can you help my out?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Checkout [StringFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat.aspx) when using Binding.

```
Title="{Binding Path=Description, StringFormat=Description: {0}}"
```

If you have the textbox and you want to use its text, it works the same way. Give the Textbox a name and use ElementName

```
Title="{Binding ElementName=myText, Path=Text, StringFormat=Description: {0}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this very easily using DataBinding

Create a field Description in ViewModel/DataContext, and use [StringFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat.aspx)

```
Title = "{Binding Path=Description,Mode=OneWay, StringFormat = Description: {0}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating an event on the Description's setter is the standard practise.  Use the `PropertyChanged` event of the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.